# Bounds in Android. Default scale?

Tags: android, drawable, bounds

When I set the bounds in a code like the following one, what is the scale?, dp? px?,

```
ShapeDrawable myLine= new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());       
myLine.setBounds(0, 0, 1, MAX_HEIGHT);
myLine.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: setBounds params are pixel size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pskink already gave the answer, but just to close it:

> setBounds params are pixel size